# git and git extensions uninstall error 2330

Tags: git, git-extensions

First I wanted to upgrade my git installation and tried it using the latest git extensions. The installation failed with error code 2330. Afterwards I've tried to both uninstall/repair my installation, but every it failed with error 2330. The visual studio addins is located in my documents which is located on a networkshare, but I have a connection to it.

Any idea to how I can remove and reinstall git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem had something to do with my company laptop. When I got back to work and tried to uninstall everything uninstalled. Maybe something to du with GIT Extensions installing into Documents located on a networkshare.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, cause was a network-shared home directory at the time when gitextensions were originally installed that no longer existed.

The way I finally fixed this:

- Disable msiexec rollback by creating registry key according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/disablerollback
- Uninstall old version of Git Extensions

This fails with usual 2330 error, however it does not roll back and the old version is effectively uninstalled.

- Re-enable msiexec rollback by removing created registry key
- Install new version of GitExtension

Comment: If you follow this, please make sure you don't forget to re-enable the rollback, otherwise you may be in deep trouble in the future.

Comment: This didn't work for me but searching within the registry for "GitPlugin" and replacing the network location with the local location fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to update all projects associated to all the repositories and then disconnecting your machine from all the repositories before updating or uninstalling. I think that error has something to do with not being able to perform changes because of possible repercussions to the projects in the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a old question, but.

pay attention about installation  folder. In my case GitExtensions Installer was trying to create a Addins folder. I create this folder by my own. And the error is gone.

In my case i was installing  if u are uninstalling maybe the wizard will try to delete some folder or file.

Sounds like some problem with user permission!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to K. eegi my error was because a network-shared home directory at the time GitExtensions was originally installed no longer existed. However, that rollback solution didnt work for me.

Instead searching within the windows registry for all keys that contained "GitPlugin" and replacing the network location with the local location fixed it (i.e. C:\Users<username>\Documents... instead of \networklocation...).